# How to create VPN between a Windows and OSX computer?

Tags: windows, macos, vpn

I have a PC (Windows XP) at my office and a Mac (OSX 10.6) at home.

With my Mac at home, I'd like to connect to the PC at work and gain access to shared files.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Update:

I only have one computer at my office. It is connected to a Linksys router which I have admin access to.

At home, I have access to my Airport Extreme router.

Comment: More details please. Do you have access to network infrastructure at the office? At home? What kind of infrastructure (routers, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using OpenVPN. The OS X version you want to use is [Tunnelblick](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/) and the Windows version is [OpenVPN Gui](http://openvpn.se/). I've set up a VPN this way before and the Gui interfaces for both these apps make the process a lot easier. You can find a very good walk-through for configuring your VPN [here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html).

EDIT: Here are some basic confs that should work, at least to get you started:

server.ovpn

```
dev tap
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
secret static.key
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
comp-lzo
```

client.ovpn

```
remote 69.62.253.158
dev tap
ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0
secret static.key
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
comp-lzo
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1
```

Comment: Love the typo: The name is Tunnelblick (German for tunnel vision).

Comment: It looks like setting up an OpenVPN server on my mac is going to be a real chore. So much that there's a whole book on this very topic?

Comment: I actually did it the other way, I had my mac as the client, which worked well, but the conf file should work either way, I'm not sure about any mac specific tweaks though, I'll post the confs I used as soon as I find them.

Comment: I posted some configs. I also should clarify, I had OS X.3 connecting to Windows 2K server with MAC sharing enabled. This feature isn't present in anything after 2K server, so results may vary.

Comment: MaQleod, +1 here. I'll mark this as accepted once I have a chance to test it out some more.